# Double Integral over Non-Rectangular Region Concept

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

In most textbooks, when a solid is under the surface $f(x,y)$ and over a rectangle $R={(x,y)|a≤x≤b,c≤y≤d}$, its volume can be calculated using double integral of $f(x,y)$ with constant bounds or constant functions for both inner integral and outer integral. When a solid is under the surface $f(x,y)$ and over a general region, the double integral can be evaluated if the bounds of the region can be stated as functions, for instance, $R={(x,y)|a≤x≤b,g_1(x)≤y≤g_2(x)}$.

Could I conclude that when a region's bounds cannot be stated as functions as perhaps, the form of the region is very complicated, so we cannot apply double integral in this case?

Comment: Do you have a specific example in mind? The bounds can always be expressed as two functions, but the functions need not be very nice.

Comment: @Dasherman, for example, the bound of the region in the "left side" for the bounds of x and in the above for the bounds of y are like zig-zag roads. so they cannot be stated as functions

Comment: Ah yes, you're right of course! You could split the zigzag into pieces, integrate over each piece and add them up again. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Dasherman, that was I thought about. ok